Can C++20 std::ranges::find_if throw exceptions?
From the std::ranges::find, std::ranges::find_if, std::ranges::find_if_not page, it does not mention exceptions, but neither are marked as noexcept.
I'm assuming that the behaviour will be the same as std::find, std::find_if, std::find_if_not. In this page it mentions the following:
Exceptions

The overloads with a template parameter named ExecutionPolicy report errors as follows:

- If execution of a function invoked as part of the algorithm throws an exception and ExecutionPolicy is one of the standard policies, std::terminate is called. For any other ExecutionPolicy, the behavior is implementation-defined.

- If the algorithm fails to allocate memory, std::bad_alloc is thrown.

So, I have two questions: 1. Is my assumption correct, and 2. will the following function be noexcept(true)?
bool checkExtensionSupport(std::span<vk::ExtensionProperties> availableExtensions, const char* extensionName) noexcept(?)
{
    auto match = [extensionName](const vk::ExtensionProperties& p) {
        return std::strcmp(p.extensionName, extensionName) == 0;
    };

    auto result = std::ranges::find_if(availableExtensions, match);
    return result != availableExtensions.end();
}

because the lambda does not do any dynamic allocations, and strcmp is noexcept.

Why bring up the parallel overloads at all?

Can you explain what do you mean @Davis Herring ? Is this what you are referring to? I have never used this before and can't even see how this relates to my question.

If you don't throw exceptions in predicate, then it won't throw.

If the predicate can or does throw an exception, then std::ranges::find_if can or will throw.

@CaioVinícius: You just quoted the description for the “overloads with a template parameter named ExecutionPolicy”, but you aren’t using one such, so I don’t know what it means that you did.

I dropped a mail to the reference page owner pointing to absens of "Exceptions" section
